# Excel VBA - Clicking a Javascript button on a page

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to click the publish button on the page but, it always throws an error

```
<a unselectable="on" href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;" class="ms-cui-ctl-large" aria-describedby="Ribbon.PublishTab.Publishing.Publish.Menu.Publish.Publish_ToolTip" mscui:controltype="Button" role="button" id="Ribbon.PublishTab.Publishing.Publish-SelectedItem" style="height: auto;"><span unselectable="on" class="ms-cui-ctl-largeIconContainer"><span unselectable="on" class=" ms-cui-img-32by32 ms-cui-img-cont-float"><img unselectable="on" alt="" src="/_layouts/1033/images/format.png" style="top: -416px; left: -128px;"></span></span><span unselectable="on" class="ms-cui-ctl-largelabel" style="height: auto;">Publish</span></a>
```

The above is the button i'm trying to click

i did try the following line of code:
`IE.Document.getElementById("Ribbon.PublishTab.Publishing.Publish-SelectedItem").Click`

but still couldn't click on the button.

Hope someone could help.

*Note: the reason i'm trying to do this is because i need to publish large number of files, so trying to automate the process*

Comment: If this website always has the same amount of <a> tags you can do IE.Document.getElementByTagName("a")(20).Click if the <a> tag is the 20th on the document. OR You will have to loop all <a> tags and identify the one you are on until you get to this one.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, since the publish button is on ribbon tab, the method you suggested only opens the publishing tab. i did try playing around with few other tags & pages, it seems the <a> tag is placed differently on each page.

Comment: Are you able to share this website?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Replace$(IE.Document.getElementById("Ribbon.PublishTab.Publishing.Publish-SelectedItem").innerHTML, "unselectable=""on""","unselectable=""off""")
```

And then click the element.

Or possibly,

```
Call ie.document.getElementById("Ribbon.PublishTab.Publishing.Publish-SelectedItem").SetAttribute("unselectable","off")
```

And then click.

Hard to say with no URL to test with and so little HTML and associated JS shown.

Comment: Hi QHarr, sorry for the delay in response, i did try the above, but it did not work. For some reason the application just doesn't go further after loading the page. Sorry couldn't provide an URL as the site is an intranet site. I'm still looking for solutions for this case.

Comment: If it would help, the file i'm trying to publish is in sharepoint 2010 site.

Comment: can you provide more html then? It would help for us to see what events might be linked etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
IE.Document.getElementById("Ribbon.PublishTab.Publishing.Publish-SelectedItem").FireEvent("onclick")
```

Comment: Hi Santosh, sorry for the late reply, i did try the above, but it doesn't work, the application just doesn't go further after loading the page.

Comment: `onclick="return false;"` tells the browser to stop following events, like follow a link.